# TCL: run proc with new process from same file

Tags: tcl, exec, proc

I'm trying to run proc with new process
I'm trying to call proc1 and proc2 from main function , but each should run separately with a new process (or subprocess) and also wait till it finish

```
    proc main { var } {
        puts "main function with var: $var"
        #call proc1 with new process
        exec proc1 1
        #wait till proc1 finish
        #call proc2 with new process
        exec proc2 2
        #wait till proc2 finish
        puts "Finished"
    }

    proc proc1 { var1 } {
        puts "proc1 function with var: $var1"
    }

    proc proc2 { var2 } {
        puts "proc2 function with var: $var2"
    }
```

I tried using exec but it did not work 
I tried googling it, but did not succeed to find a solution

How can I make it run ?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: if you want separate process, then keep those procs in separate file and call them with `tclsh` process

Comment: Consider using threads for this. They are a lot easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest mechanism is to put the procedures in a separate file (e.g., `myprocs.tcl`) with the following bit of extra code at the *end* of the file:

```
# Take a command from stdin, evaluate it, and write result to stdout
puts [eval [read stdin]]
```

Then you call those procedures using the following helper:

```
proc runproc {procname args} {
    exec [info nameofexecutable] myprocs.tcl << [list $procname {*}$args] 2>@stderr
}

# Demonstrating
set result [runproc proc1 1]
```

---

The above isn't the most robust mechanism however. In particular, if you have a bug in your procedures, things will go quite wonky. Here's a more robust mechanism that works very well provided you change your procedures to `return` their results instead of `puts`ing them:

Callee side:

```
set cmd [read stdin]
catch $cmd msg opts
puts [list $msg $opts]
exit
```

Caller side:

```
proc runproc {procname args} {
    set cmd [list $procname {*}$args]
    set pair [exec [info nameofexecutable] myprocs.tcl << $cmd 2>@stderr]
    lassign $pair msg opts
    return -options $opts $msg
}
```

Transferring a normal `stdout` across at the same time, or allowing the subprocess to access the caller's `stdin`, requires more work again to move the command-and-control channel to be other than a standard pipe, and the above is good enough for a lot of things.